Wrinkles in shade auto smooth
I Used a Boolean modifier to make windows on a curved mesh and shaded it auto smooth now I have wrinkles in my mesh.

I have no Idea how to fix this or another way to cut windows in to my mesh. Could somebody help me fix this or give me a better method for cutting windows?


Maybe use this topology instead:

Begin with that hole:

Bevel the corners:

Join the vertices to get this topology:

Dissolve the other edges:


I've tried recreating you topology but I can't could you explain how you got it to this state? I'm not very good with blender.

I've edited my post, I hope it helps

The large face with cut-out holes is non-planar, which poses problems during rendering. To ensure planarity within your example, all encircled vertices must have the same Y position as the plane's vertices' Y position. Even better, consider changing the topology as demonstrated by @moonboots' answer.

